# Git - Keep commits done by a specific author

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a branch that I was working on.

My co-workers accidentally merged their branches into mine and now all the commits are all over the place.

I can't cherry pick coz there are hundreds of commits.

How do I keep only my changes in the branch?

Basically, I'm looking for a way to just keep my commits on the branch and discard any other commits done by other users.

Comment: You can create a new branch from your last commit. This new branch only contains your code. But you need to create a branch from your last commit.

Comment: Yes that's right. I was however looking for a username based approach for keeping commits on my branch. Sad, that `git` does not have this feature.

Comment: Yaa git does not have this feature

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the new branch solution hinted at by [Nivrutti Pawar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7940044/nivrutti-pawar) and [Shakil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339013/shakil), I'd suggest you could also restore the branch to its pre-merge state.

Explicit steps below.

---

**Phase 1 : locate the merge commit** (if you didn't do anything since the bad merge, go directly to phase 2 and use `HEAD^` for the `<bad-commit>`)

```
# in case you're not presently on your branch
git checkout your-branch

# now we need to spot the merge commit where things went awry,
# it's probably not too far in your history, so spot its commit hash in the log
git log --oneline
```

In the output list you should be able to determine what is the commit hash of the bad merge, I'll just use `<bad-commit>` for the purpose of the example.

**Phase 2 : go back in history**

```
# Rewind history to the point just BEFORE the bad merge, so mind the caret
git reset --hard <bad-commit>^
```

At this point your branch is in the state it was just before the merge, but you'll need to force-push it to your remote to reflect this new history, so be sure to inform your coworkers beforehand, and then

```
git push --force origin HEAD
```

(And since you're not alone on the project, maybe take a [look](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---force-with-leaseltrefnamegt) at `--force-with-lease`)

Comment: I'd done exactly the same. I was wondering if there's something that can automatically keep commits based on the usernames. Nevertheless, this solves my problem. Hence, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add one more thing with [Nivrutti pawar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7940044/nivrutti-pawar) in this case we can use `git-reflog`[link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and check all actions of us in individual local machine and can able to go just before the mess action and start a new branch.